# Cannot access nodejs server from outside ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a web service on aws ec2 windows server 2008 r2 instance, but am unable to access the server using its public ip outside the instance. The port my application is hosted on as 3333. I have added rules for SSH, HTTP and ICMP in my security group but still cannot access it externally. 
I can connect to the machine via RDP but cannot even ping the ip from my local machine. Is it something not supported on amazon free 12 month account?
Have been struggling with this for a while, any help appreciated. Below attached is the snapshot for my selected security group for the instance.

[image]
Thanks,
Aakash

Comment: Nothing relatives to `free tier account` here. I think there are some possible reasons: 1. Window Server does not support `SSH` in normal case => cannot ping `ssh port`. 2. Did you setup port `3333` for `ICMP` and `HTTP` rule? 3. You should use some `telnet/netcat` tool to check connection. Do not use `ping`. 4. Is your `NodeJS app` running well?

Comment: I've updated the question with snapshot of the security group. My nodeJS app is running well on ec2 and I am able to access it on the ec2 browser at 3333

Comment: You already opened all. Can you give me how you use to ping your server? What is the command? Your local server inside company or your home's network? If inside company's network, there are many thing to check.

Comment: I just use ping and the ip address of the ec2 on my local windows instance cmd. I've also tried ping using the DNS name of the instance. Its inside my company network.

Comment: If your service is running well in server, I guess cause of your company's firewall. As your IT team

Answer (score 3):

You can access your server from anywhere even if you have free tier. You just need to add correct inbound rules in the associated security group. In your case, rules seem fine but the windows defender must be blocking all the incoming requests. You can try turning off the windows defender in your windows ec2 instance by **searching "Windows Defender Firewall" -> click "Turn windows defender firewall on or off" -> select "Turn off windows defender firewall(not recommended)" for public requests**.

I was facing the same issue. Turning it off worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I has nothing to do with free tier. You need to allow the ports which you want to access from public. Please go to security groups and allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have allow your server to public access.For giving access go to security group in that inbound rule and allow them to public access.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).